# Partitioning a Regular Polygon into Smaller Ones

Tags: combinatorics

The vertexes of a regular polygon are colored in some fashion such that each set of all vertexes having the same color is the set of vertices of a regular polygon. Then there are two congruent polygons among them (of course we exclude the coloring of the polygon in one color).

I've made a trivial observation that this is equivalent to:

If $d_1, d_2, ..., d_k \neq 1, 2$ are divisors of $n \geq 3$ and given that $d_1 + d_2 + ... + d_k = n$, prove that two of the $d_i$'s must be equal.

But I haven't gone much further. I've tried to use generating functions in this way:

We can let 
\begin{align*}
f_1(X) & = X^{a_1} + X^{a_1 + d_1} + ... + X^{a_1 + n - d_1} \\
f_2(X) & = X^{a_2} + X^{a_2 + d_2} + ... + X^{a_2 + n - d_2} \\
& \vdots \\
f_c(X) & = X^{a_c} + X^{a_c + d_c} + ... + X^{a_c + n - d_c}
\end{align*}
be the polygons where the $a_i$ are the smallest vertices. Then we know that when we sum them, 
$$\sum_{i = 1}^c X^{a_i} \left ( \frac{X^n-1}{X^{d_i} - 1} \right ) = \frac{X^n-1}{X-1}$$
or $$\sum_{i = 1}^c \frac{X^{a_i}}{1 - X^{d_i}} = \frac{1}{1-X}$$

which means that we can partition $\mathbb{N}_0$ in $\{a_i + kd_i\}_{0 \leq k}$ for $i = 1,2,3,...,c$ though this doesn't seem to help very much.

Comment: Not sure if this helps, but $\sum\limits_{i=1}^c\,\frac{1}{d_i}=1$ must hold.

Comment: this is equivalent to the second problem I stated.

Comment: My comment above is a consequence of your second problem, but not equivalent.  By the way, note that $4+8+12=24$.  So, the first observation (about $\sum\limits_{i=1}^c\,d_i=n$) alone is not true.

Answer (score 1):

Suppose that $d_c$ is the largest and $d_i<d_c$ for all $i=1,2,\ldots,c-1$.  Then, the equality 
$$\sum_{i=1}^c\,f_i(X)=X^{n-1}+X^{n-2}+\ldots+X+1$$
implies that, when $X:=\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\text{i}}{d_c}\right)$,
$$d_c\,\exp\left(\frac{2\pi\text{i}a_c}{d_c}\right)=0\,,$$
which is a contradiction.  This shows that the two smallest elements (i.e., with fewest numbers of sides) of every partition of a regular polygon into smaller regular polygons have the same size.

Comment: I think the two smaller polygons (ie, the ones will the least number of sides) should be equal.

Comment: so wouldn't you have to use the $d$ that is the smallest?

Comment: Yes, you are right.  The divisor $d_i$ corresponds to a $\left(\frac{n}{d_i}\right)$-gon.